# How to set the default tab of multiple swipe views with tabs?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-studio, swipeview

I am really stuck. I did four Swipe Views with Tabs in my main activity but what I want is when user opens the application it shows automatically the second tab not the first one.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "First Tab", "Second Tab", "Third Tab", "Fourth Tab" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

And this is my main_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 14):

The second tab is index 1, all you should need to do is add a setCurrentItem to change the current tab to the correct one after you have setup the page change listener.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paged);

    ... code omitted ...

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     **/
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {...}

    // set the default tab to the second tab   
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to make the desired tab selected

suppose if you want to select the second tab to be default selected tab then

```
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
```

will do the same