# How to space tab layout text

Tags: java, android, tabs

I am building an android app with tabs but the result I am getting is not what I wish for. I will like to implement something similar to what whatsapp has.

Below is what I want to do:

**My Tab**

[image: my app's screenshot]

**Whatsapp**

[image: whatsapp screenshot]

Comment: How and where do you declare your TabLayout? Could you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved like below

By xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

And programatically

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this line inside Tablayout  `app:tabGravity="fill"`

for example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Comment: thank you very much. this solved my problem. But please how do i set the middle one as my default selected tab?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454220/how-to-set-the-default-tab-of-multiple-swipe-views-with-tabs